# Adding a random number in front of a UI Label

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add a random number in front of my UI label this is my code which is not working.

```
@IBOutlet var Label2: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet var Label1: UILabel!
Label1.text! = "1"
Label2.text! = "2"
var random = arc4random_uniform(2) + 1

if Label(random).text! == "1" {
    print("This is Label 1")
} else {
    print ("This is Label 2")
}
```

If there is any other way to add a random number in front of UI Label i'll welcome the answer.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of these.

Comment: @t4nhpt I can not tell you the purpose. I want to know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your labels into an array and then pick a random one:

```
@IBOutlet var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label2: UILabel!

var labels = [UILabel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    labels.append(label1)
    labels.append(label2)

    var random = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))

    if labels[random].text! == "1" {
        print("This is Label 1")
    } else {
        print ("This is Label 2")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use IBOutletCollection

```
@IBOutlet var label: [UILabel]!
label[0].text! = "1"
label[1].text! = "2"
var random:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))

if label[random].text! == "1" {
    print("This is Label 1")
} else {
    print ("This is Label 2")
}
```

UPDATE:

1. make sure all the labels you want in the array is highlighted
2. right click and drag to your collection view
3. set connection to Outlet Collection

[image]

Comment: I have 2 UI Labels in my main story board and this will only connect with one.

Comment: there's a difference between "Outlet" and "Outlet Collection", i think you got confused. Do read again for the updated answer and try it out yourself.

Comment: btw it should be Int(arc4random_uniform(2)) for the proper casting

Comment: @Angelina, i updated the answer and tested it in a sample project. I can send you the sample project if you need it.

Comment: Can you send the sample project. I am getting a label **Expected Declaration Error**

Comment: sure, i would need your email though

Comment: Can you upload it on any cloud storage and make it public plz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92797/discussion-between-francis-yeap-and-angelina).

Comment: Thank you. But pkacprzak approach works best with my work. You thought me about Outlet Collection too appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you're trying to achieve with `Label(random)` is to dynamically change the **Label** variable name. As pointed in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716931/create-a-variable-in-swift-with-dynamic-name), this is probably a bad practice. So, I would recommend you read [Create a variable in swift with dynamic name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716931/create-a-variable-in-swift-with-dynamic-name), first.

[edit:]
Just to give **an example**, you  can do that using an Array, such as:

```
// Creating two UILabels:
var label1 = UILabel()
var label2 = UILabel()

label1.text = "0"
label2.text = "1"

// An array of Labels, which starts from 0:
let labels: [UILabel] = [label1, label2]
// Another random function which goes to the size of the array:
var i = random() % labels.count

// Just to check the random number:
print("Your random number: \(i)")

// And then, the test:
if labels[i].text == "0" {
    print("This is Label 0: \(labels[i].text)")
} else {
    print ("This is Label 1: \(labels[i].text)")
}
```

Just apply these ideas to your **IBOutlet** variables.

Hope it helps :D

Comment: This is about a UILabel not just a Label Variable