# Naming Sprites compared to i in for loop(swift)

Tags: swift, for-loop

I was running into this problem that instead of writing this:

```
let enemy1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")
let enemy2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")
let enemy3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")
```

over and over again and making a thousand enemies, I would just make a for loop like this:

```
for i in 1...1000{
    let enemy(i) = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")
}
```

but as you would know just doing enemy(i) doesn't work.
If you know the answer to this problem or can help me in any way by sugesting any other technique please reply.
Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: That makes little point.  Are you going to position 1,000 copies of the same guy at the same location?

Comment: El Tomato No I'm going to make them spawn at different locations but I didn't want to complicate the code and wanted to make it simple to understand. Thank you for asking

Comment: for loop should be like this:  for i in 1...1000 { }

Comment: Change let enemy(i) = to let enemy =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for statement is like this:

```
for value in range {
   statements
}
```

I've written a simple example:
As  @ColGraff mentiond. for the name of the enemy you can code like this: `SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy\(i)")`. but not as the name of the variable.

```
var enemy = [SKSpriteNode]()
for _ in 1...1000 {
   enemy.append(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy"))
   // or use this:
   // enemy[i] = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")

}
```

Comment: That's a terrible solution.

Comment: @ElTomato I've changed it

Comment: @SebastianSigurdarson Why do you need naming them like this when you can have an array?  look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716931/create-a-variable-in-swift-with-dynamic-name

Comment: @FattanehTalebi you're a geniuse.. Thank you so much for the answers and making me realize this